# Geometrical introduction to Caccioppoli sets

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

Can anyone suggest me a geometrical introduction to Caccioppoli sets, a.k.a sets of finite perimeter. [This](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Perimeter) Encyclopedia of Mathematics article states a definition of the perimeter of a set in terms of approximating sequences of open sets with smooth boundary and says that this can be found in modern textbooks. However all the books I've looked into give an analytical definition for the perimeter in terms of the variation measure of the characteristic function of the set. I understand that this is more convenient to set up the theory but I am curious to see a more geometric approach. Any references are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Try the text by Enrico Giusti - not sure if it will provide you the definition you will seek but it is the standard reference on such things from what I remember.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it starts off with BV functions as well.

Comment: Try Maggi's book: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/sets-of-finite-perimeter-and-geometric-variational-problems/F8D0DABFFFB0D444C5AD5D37B3E3DBC1